# CRM Business rule that uses multiple lines of text

Tags: dynamics-crm, business-rules, dynamics-crm-2015

Is it possible to create a business rule where I can set the value for a textbox with multiple lines. The text would be fixed inside the rule and would have multiple lines.

In the UI I have found that you can set the value as one-line text.
[image]

There is a workaround with javascript or a hidden field and default text in that field, but I am searching for a simple solution with only business rule.

Comment: Apparently there is no way to do it. The easiest way is to set the desired text on form load event in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better using a workflow for this situation. You have a richer text editor where you can type in multiple lines.

Not sure how well the native controls of a business rule will support this (if at all).

Comment: That's one way to do it. But the requirement was that in case the field is empty, it must be filled with predefined text on form load, not after save, so the user can see the text immediately.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this with business rules is that the text will be changed in the future. The client wanted to change text by himself without the knowledge of the programming. Therefore I thought of using business rules. Anyway. It can't b done so I switched to javascript.